# When $z \to 0$, can we approximate the hyperbolic distance between $z$ and $0$ by the usual Euclidean distance?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
Let $\rho$ represent the hyperbolic metric on the open unit disk and $|z|$ be the usual length of $z$,
when $z \to 0$, can we say that $\rho(z , 0) \to |z|$?

I just want to know whether this is true.
Some intuitive explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the metric $$\rho(z,w) = 2\operatorname{arctanh}^{-1}\bigg|\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}\bigg|$$ ? (Or some multiple thereof?) If so, yes it does mimic the typical Euclidean distance (modulo a multiplicative factor) since $\operatorname{arctanh}$ near $0$ is approximately linear which can be seen by its Taylor series. Any "good" geometric .. metric .. should reduce down to the Euclidean in the limit.

Comment: In line with @CameronWilliams' comment, if you're working with a chart on any manifold it "feels" right to be able to approximate small distances with the euclidean metric. You have to be careful with the coordinate chart because it is a homeomorphism and usually not an isometry, but because it's continuous you should be able to approximate distances with the euclidean metric in a similar way to approximating the arc length of a smooth curve using the euclidean metric in calculus. As said above "Any "good" geometric .. metric .. should reduce down to the Euclidean in the limit."